# Opening a shapefile with roads, how to display the road names?

Tags: shapefile, c#, arcgis-engine

I am using

```
((AxMapControl)myMap.AddShapeFile( directory, shapeFileName)
```

To display a shapefile which has road data.  Now the roads display properly, but the road names aren't displaying.  How can I turn on the roads?

I don't need exact instructions just point me in the right direction please. I'm sorry this is such a novice question.  I'm using ArcEngine 2010 and C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the layer symbology in ArcMap and save it as a *.lyr and load the shape file using the *.lyr file [Sample_Save_a_layerfile](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Save_a_layer_file_in_a_MapControl_application/0001000003v5000000/). The benefit to do this using a lyr-file is that you can easily change it later on without changing the code. Take a look here if you want to do it in code: [Working with labels and annotation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Working_with_labels_and_annotation/0001000000nt000000/)

Just to display the attribute:

```
ILayer layer = axMapControl1.Map.get_Layer(0);
IGeoFeatureLayer geoLayer = layer as IGeoFeatureLayer;
geoLayer.DisplayAnnotation = true;
axMapControl1.Refresh(esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewAll, null, null);
```

Comment: I just clicked "label features in this layer" , and saved and it worked, do you have any idea how to do this sequence programatically in ArcEngine?

Comment: Updated with resource on how to add labels using code.